# MVC DisplayNameAttribute and Ninject: Possible?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject, ninject-2, ninject.web.mvc

Let's assume following basic Project-Setup:

```
- Core
-- Attributes
--- CustomDisplayNameAttribute : DisplayNameAttribute
- UI
```

UI represents the MVC Web interface, the core implements all the domain business objects, including self written attributes like `CustomDisplayNameAttribute`. This attribute contains additional dependencies like a language resolver, which e.g. deals with fallback orders. Hibernate sessions would be another possible dependency.

In earlier projects, these attributes did a global request in order to get the resolver. This is IMO ugly and should be handled differently. Furthermore, Core should stay without `HttpContext`: since the language-resolver is required per request, it might end up in `HttpContext` Items Collection.

Now I am quite a beginner with **Ninject**, and I am not sure if it is the right tool in order to get such dependencies into something like a `CustomDisplayNameAttribute`?

In words it would be something like this:

- If the attribute is created, populate the additional language resolver property with the language resolver from `HttpContext` Items Collection
- If there is no `HttpContext` (e.g. testing, quartz jobs etc.), get it from somewhere else.

Thx for any inputs

**Edit:** Sample-Code

```
namespace Core.Attributes
{
    public class CustomDisplayNameAttribute : DisplayNameAttribute
    {

        private string textCode;

        /// <param name="textCode">According to this Text-Code, we will load
        /// and resolve the text.</param>
        public DeimosDisplayNameAttribute(string textCode)
        {
            this.textCode = textCode;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Load and resolve Text according to Text-Code
        /// </summary>
        public override string DisplayName
        {
            get 
            {
                // Load - Ooops: First global access 
                // --> How can it be injected with IoC?
                TextbausteinRepository repo = Root.GetTextBausteinRepository();
                var textItem = repo.GetText(textCode);
                // Resolve - Ooops: Second global access
                // --> How can it be injected with IoC?
                TextResolver resolver = Root.GetTextResolver();
                return resolver.resolve(textItem);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Edit 2:** In that context, it seems that there is no way around a global access, like a registry pattern or similar. UI would register the needed data in there, and the attributes would access it from there. We started to think about storing it in `ThreadLocal<T>`, but this seems not really save due to the fact that there is a possibility of thread-swapping during the life-cycle. So there seems no way around storing `HttpContext` in the registry layer. For more info about this subject, see [Cup(Of T)][1].

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to do.  Could you provide some example source code?

Comment: Added the code-sample of `CustomDisplayNameAttribute` which should show the dependencies which I would like to resolve somehow, without any global requests.

Comment: So what you're saying is that you want to use Dependency Injection with attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, because data attributes are not run-time dispatched like filters are.  As such, there's no place to intercept the creation and inject what you're looking for.